# How do I change the gradle version in flutter module?

Tags: java, android, flutter

I am developing flutter module to integrate with android application. I have created the flutter module using the command

```
flutter create -t module --org com.example my_flutter
```

I want to integrate this module with existing android app, which is built using gradle version 6.5. So I want to build my_flutter module on same gradle version. Where do I update my gradle version?

Flutter module, `.android` folder is generated one, I cannot update in `build.gradle` of `.android`. So where exactly should update the version?

Answer (score -1):

To change the downloaded gradle for your project go to android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties and change the distributionUrl (this link contains the distribution urls
https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/&ved=2ahUKEwjwpIP8x6L-AhV5M1kFHbsABukQFnoECCAQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0or8fxh6nANEHU2Je_rsql)
Then delete the .gradle folder then try to build or run your app
(PLEASE MAKE SURE TO MAKE COPY OF THE FOLDER BEFORE DELETING IT)
Then the new gradle will start to download

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But flutter module does not contain android folder. That is the problem. all It has  .android folder(generated one) which  we can't edit. flutter module is created using command  "flutter create -t module --org com.example my_flutter" . So we have to edit the config file where flutter create command reads while creating the module. But I am not able to locate that file